# using select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For the select box, i'm using an array which i declare it myself through a method. The array are numbers with a range from 1 to 100 which is from a method i created in the controller.

array is declared from the following method in controller:

```
@print = Print.find(params[:id])
@pages = (1..(@print.number_of_images_entry)).to_a
```

I'm trying to do it with this:

```
<%= select ( "blackwhite", "newpages", ... ... ) %>
```

but i am having difficulty in understanding the [explaination](http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Select-helper-methods-in-Ruby-on-Rails) as with the id part of "select" code:

```
<%= select ("selected_payment", "id", @payments.map {|u| [u.name,u.id]}) %>
```

edit:

blackwhite is another model.

Comment: it could help you http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on this subject because it seems to be a tricky one for people (including myself!) to understand.

http://www.fmhcc.com.au/ruby/rails/using-collection_select-in-rails/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have looked at collection_select (read your website) and it isn't something i would use as the data is not exactly being read from the database.

Except for a value which is from a model which i would convert into an array (with a method) and store those values in another model.

Answer (score 0):

Well from the example link that you provided, it shows that in the first example is using a hash that is being used to populate the options tags. The second example takes the object name `selected_payment` it then takes the method which is an attribute of that instance variable. So in other words. The instance variable being used for `selected_payment` is id. The instance variable  is converted into an array of arrays using `.map` which is an enumerable for returning a new array with a set of results. So in the provided example

```
<%= select ("selected_payment", "id", @payments.map {|u| [u.name,u.id]}) %>
```

It returns an array of the payments that include the name and the id that corresponds to that name.

From my understanding I've come up with the following:

```
<% ("blackwhite", "id", @print.map {|p| [p.number, p.id]}) %>
```

May not be correct but its what I've gathered from the link you provided and from what you are trying to do